# What is the meaning of 封闭式 in 四合院内便形成一个封闭式的小环境？

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 只要关闭起大门，四合院内便形成一个封闭式的小环境。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 14.

What is the meaning of 封闭式？

I understand that 封闭 means "closed" and 式 means "style/type", yet I don't understand what "closed style" means. What is the use of 式? The sentence can make sense without it.

Comment: Google 封闭(closed) and 式(style/type)

Comment: I don't think this thread is asking for translation as many others on this forum. It is unfairly picked for close.

Comment: Yes I don't understand what it means "closed style". What is the use of 式? All the sentence can make sense without it.

Comment: Closing a question is intended to prompt [edit]ing to make it suitable for the site; we can reopen it afterwards.  If the question is left in its original form, it could attract low-quality "let me Google that for you" answers (along the lines of Tang Ho's comment above) which neither help the OP nor the site.  So, let's edit to make it on-topic.

Comment: @Konstantinos Agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote:- "The sentence can make sense without it"

Yes, but it would not be "proper" composite writing.

Consider the following sentences in English:-

(1) We have a cozy back garden which closes us from the noisy world outside.

(2) We have a cozy back garden which closes us off from the noisy world outside.

The meanings of both are the same, but would the additional "off" somehow give a better composite sense to the sentence?

So, the word 式, by itself meaning style/type, has no individual defining semantics, (just like "type / style"), unless it is paired with some other grammatical feature, before or after. For example:-

--- French cooking /  French style cooking.

--- Brotherly love / Brotherly type of love.

Thus what "closed style / type" 封闭式 means, and what specific role 式 plays in it would depend on what follows or precedes it as by itself 式 is semantically "neutral". Just like when you say "type", what type?, "style", what style?

So examples of 封闭式 :-

--- 封闭式基金 -- "Closed-end Fund", as in some financial investment fund.

--- -封闭式踏板 -- "Closed / enclosed pedal", as on a bicycle.

Thus 封闭 simply means anything which has a certain "closed off" feature, (physical or otherwise), from "outside", or "outside influence" and 式 simply expresses the "type or style" of the closed off feature in question.

Hence, I suppose, this accounts for @Tang Ho's short answer because 封闭式 is too general and "featureless" on its own, though your accompanying sentence does provide a context, namely, "...四合院内便形成一个封闭式的小环境", where the 四合院内, "inside / internal courtyard" provides the 式, "the type" of 封闭, "closed" feature which gives rise to the 小环境, "micro- environment"

Answer (score 0):

封闭式的 means "closed style".

"只要关闭起大门，四合院内便形成一个封闭式的小环境." - "It only needs to close down the gate, then the interior of the 四合院 shapes into a cozy, closed-style environment."

IMO, the sentence sounds better, if 式(style) is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the word "封闭" is negative somehow, more like not willing to be open , but the appending a character "式", makes it more neutral and objective.